# Using conditional to rename the values of a column with awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I am using a dataset with a field called "Store" at the second column of the dataset.

```
"Store"
  A
  B
  C
  A
```

The following code is not working. What I want is to rename "A" values to "A_store"

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {FS=","} {if (NR!=1 && $2=="A") $2="A_store"}' output.csv
```

The desired output:

```
"Store"
A_store
B_store
C_store
A_store
```

Comment: and the actual output is?

Comment: Why does your desired output show changed "B" and "C" values if you want to change "A" values?

Comment: Please post the full fields (at least including the 1st field) of the dataset to make the data and your script coherent.

Comment: `-F,` is one way to set FS. `FS=","` is another way to set FS. You don't need to do both. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to write awk scripts.

Comment: *code is not working* can you be more lucid? Did you get any error? If yes what it stated? Did you get incorrect output? If second what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal isn't clear to me, but perhaps this will help:

```
cat test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
A, 1, 5, q
B, 2, 6, r
C, 3, 7, s
A, 4, 8, t

awk -F"," '{if(NR>1) $1=$1"_store"; print}' test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
A_store  1  5  q
B_store  2  6  r
C_store  3  7  s
A_store  4  8  t

awk -F"," '{if(NR>1 && $1=="A") $2=$1"_store"; print}' test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
A A_store  5  q
B, 2, 6, r
C, 3, 7, s
A A_store  8  t

awk -F"," '{if(NR>1 && $1 == "A") $2=$1"_store"; else if(NR>1) $2=$1; print}' test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
A A_store  5  q
B B  6  r
C C  7  s
A A_store  8  t
```

Also, if you have whitespace in your strings you will need to alter your code slightly, e.g.

```
cat test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
  A, 1, 5, q
  B, 2, 6, r
  C, 3, 7, s
  A, 4, 8, t

awk -F"," '{if(NR>1 && $1 ~ "A") $1=$1"_store"; print}' test.txt
"Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
  A_store  1  5  q
  B, 2, 6, r
  C, 3, 7, s
  A_store  4  8  t
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: The second code worked flawless, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome; sorry for misunderstanding your problem, but I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

if OP wanted to retain commas (as hinted by "`output.csv`"), then something like

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
"misc","Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
  ,A, 1, 5, q
  ,B, 2, 6, r
  ,C, 3, 7, s
  ,A, 4, 8, t
```

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk 'BEGIN{ _+=_^=FS=OFS="," } sub("^A$","&_store",$_)^!_' 

   or

{m,g}awk 'sub("^A$","&_store",$(!_+!_))^_' FS=, OFS=,

   or

{m,g}awk 'sub("^A$","&_store",$2)^_' FS=',' OFS=','
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
"misc","Store", "something else", "another thing", "last thing"
  ,A_store, 1, 5, q
  ,B, 2, 6, r
  ,C, 3, 7, s
  ,A_store, 4, 8, t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# data.csv
foo,"Store",bar
1,AA,1
2,B,1
3,C,1
4,A,1 
 
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR>1&&$2=="A"{$2=$2"_store"}1' data.csv
foo,"Store",bar
1,AA,1
2,B,1
3,C,1
4,A_store,1
```

trim whitespaces

```
# data.csv
foo,"Store",bar
1,AA,1
2,B,1
3,  A  ,1
4,A,1

$ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR>1 && $2 ~ /^[ ]*A[ ]*$/ {gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $2); gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); $2=$2"_store"}1' data.csv
foo,"Store",bar
1,AA,1
2,B,1
3,A_store,1
4,A_store,1
```